# Highlighting duplicate values in a column in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: excel, formula, openoffice-calc

I'm using a Linux machine and I've been trying to find an equivalent to excel's

```
"highlight Cell Rules > Duplicate Values"
```

formula that I can use to color cells that have duplicates on the column in OpenOffice Calc. 
I've already found and tried

```
COUNTIF(A$1:A$15; A1)>1
```

as a formula but this doesn't work on every single item in the column vs every single other one.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula works for me, *provided* I select the range (A1:A15) from the bottom up. The CF formula must be appropriate for the active cell (the one with a heavy border).

Alternatively, select top down and with the heavy border around A15 adapt your formula to insert a `5` immediately before the closing parenthesis.